# Tem como pegar o event.preventDefault() se a chamada tiver parâmetros?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo uma operação onde eu tenho a chamada de um método, neste caso especifico como eu poderia pegar o `event.preventDefault()` do formulário.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AdicionarEditarRegistro('@controller','Edit')">Salvar</button>
```

Exemplo:

```
function AdicionarEditarRegistro(controller, action) {
  debugger;

  var t = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
  var urlCompleto = "/" + controller + "/"+ action +"/";
  var formulario = $("#FormularioCompleto");

  alert('pegar o :' + 'event.preventDefault()');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar o `event` como argumento para a função. Em atributos JavaScript, o `event` está no escopo.

```js
function handle(name, event) {
  console.log(name); // Luiz
  console.log(typeof event.preventDefault); // function
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handle('Luiz', event)">Clique-me!</button>
```

Como curiosidade, assim como você pode passar o `event`, você também pode passar `this`. :)

---

Como alternativa, se você não quiser usar atributos para determinar os eventos, pode criar `data-attributes` e usar o `addEventListener`. Algo assim:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const name = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
  
  console.log(name); // Luiz
  console.log(typeof event.preventDefault); // function
});
```

```html
<button data-name="Luiz">Clique-me!</button>
```

Eu pessoalmente prefiro essa segunda abordagem, já que deixo o JavaScript cuidar dos eventos, limitando o papel do HTML e aumentando a separação de responsabilidades.

Comment: Agadeço a ajuda! deu certo!