# Como referenciar um item JS apartir de um elemento DOM

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um To do List usando MVC, tenho um array que salva as tarefas adicionadas pelo usuario e apartir desse array eu crio elementos no DOM. Tem como eu referenciar o item especifico do array apartir de um click no DOM? Por exemplo, como posso excluir um item da lista quando seu elemento DOM for excluido?
 Eu tentei o codigo abaixo, utilizando o ${tarefa} para passar o objeto que quero alterar, so que não funciona pois o elemento deixa de ser uma referencia ao objeto. Tem alguma outra forma de conseguir alterar o objeto especifico?

```
return array.lista.map(tarefa => {
  return `<button onclick='controller.conclui(event, ${tarefa})'></button>`
}).join('');
```

Edit. 
entendi, eu teria que passar um indentificador para conseguir uma referencia ao objeto que quero editar, mas teria alguma forma de conseguir uma referencia direta? como é possivel com React, como por exemplo:

```
       {tarefas.map(tarefa => (
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={event => onButtonClick(event, tarefa)}
          key={tarefa}
        >
         {tarefa.classe} 
        </button>

      ))}
```

pois nesse caso eu consigo acessar as propriedades do meu objeto 'tarefa' diretamente, mas não sei se tem como conseguir esse efeito com js puro

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Tem como pegar o event.preventDefault() se a chamada tiver parâmetros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446545/tem-como-pegar-o-event-preventdefault-se-a-chamada-tiver-par%c3%a2metros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui o efeito que eu queria com o seguinte codigo:

```
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const tarefas = ["tarefa1", "tarefa2", "tarefa3"];

app.innerHTML = `
<h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
<div>
  Exemplo
</div>
`;

tarefas.forEach(tarefa => {
  const button = document.createElement("button");

  button.innerHTML = `Click ${tarefa}`;
  button.onclick = function() {
    console.log("to aqui no onclick", tarefa);
  };

  app.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema da sua função é que ela está sendo gerada a partir de uma string.

Uma string não tem como armazenar uma referencia para o seu array de tarefas, você precisaria armazenar algum tipo de identificador (um número ou uma string) na sua tarefa, e utilizar esse identificador para encontrar a tarefa no seu array.

Exemplo:

```
array.lista.map(tarefa =>
    `<button onclick='conclui(event, ${tarefa.id})'></button>`
).join('');
```

---

```
function conclui(event, id) {
    // encontra a tarefa com o id recebido
    var tarefa = array.lista.find(tarefa => tarefa.id === id);
    tarefa.concluida = true;
}
```

---

---

A outra opção seria não gerar a sua função através de uma string, e sim a partir de código, dessa forma sim você poderia enviar um objeto como parâmetro

```
var botoes = array.lista.map(tarefa => {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.onclick = (event) => conclui(event, tarefa);
    return button;
});
```

---

```
function conclui(event, tarefa) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como já avisaram, não tem como passar o objeto na template string, mas voce pode passar o id e refazer sua funcao conclui.

Sendo assim, você poderia utilizar desestruturação para pegar o id e passar para o método:

```js
array.map( ({id}) => ( 
  <button onclick = "conclui(${id})">Remover Tarefa</button>)

).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, podes passar `this` como argumento, ou usar esse `event` e ler a propriedade `target` que será o elemento do DOM clicado.

Seria assim:

```js
const controller = {
  conclui(evento, button, algo) {
    console.log(button.tagName, evento.target === button); // true
  }
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick='controller.conclui(event, this, "${tarefa}")'>
                        Clica-me!</button>
```

Comment: O problema que estou encontrando com esse codigo é que o objeto tarefa é passado como string, e queria saber se tem alguma forma de conseguir uma referencia direta sem ter que usar indentificadores

Comment: @JoséSantos qual é o valor desse `tarefa`?

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas essa tarefa é um objeto js

Comment: @JoséSantos pensei que querias uma referência ao `button`, foi isso que respondi. Não era isso que querias? Esse objeto tarefas, se é uma string podes fazer `JSON.parse()` dentro de `controller.conclui` para converter em objeto...