# Como acessar o elemento que ativou o evento sem utilizar jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o código que utiliza jQuery a seguir que acessa o elemento que ativou o evento para que eu possa obter uma propriedade. Como posso fazer algo parecido sem a biblioteca em questão?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn_pag').on("click", function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('value'); // Ao clicar no botao alterar apenas esse valor!
        console.log(value);
        // Restante do código...
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="card">Pagar com Cartão</a>
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="boleto">Gerar Boleto</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Utilizar o mecanismo de *closures* da linguagem

Como no JavaScript "puro" precisamos iterar sobre o `NodeList` (retornado por métodos como `querySelectorAll`) para adicionar cada *listener* de evento, podemos fazer uso do [mecanismo de *closures*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/69296) para ter acesso ao botão no qual adicionamos o *listener* dentro do escopo léxico do próprio *callback*.

Assim:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_pag');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(btn.getAttribute('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="card">Pagar com Cartão</a>
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="boleto">Gerar Boleto</a>
```

Note, no código acima, que, mesmo dentro do *callback* do *event listener*, ainda temos acesso ao `btn` de cada iteração do [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Utilizar os *closures* é, na minha opinião, a forma mais clara para se fazer isso, já que *sempre* irá se referir ao elemento que *registrou* o evento. Como veremos a seguir, esse nem sempre é o caso nas opções a seguir.

## Utilizar o `this`

Uma outra opção é utilizar o `this`. Note que neste caso, o uso de um *function expression* (e não *arrow functions*) é mandatório, já que o `addEventListener` não é capaz de modificar o `this` de uma *arrow function*.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_pag');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="card">Pagar com Cartão</a>
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="boleto">Gerar Boleto</a>
```

Note que o `this` irá se referir ao elemento que *ativou* o evento. Desse modo, ele não será, necessariamente, o elemento que *registrou* o evento. Consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener#O_valor_de_this_no_manipulador) para saber mais.

## Utilizar `event.target`

E por fim você também pode optar por utilizar a propriedade `target`, da instância do evento passada como parâmetro para o *callback* do *event listener*:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_pag');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="card">Pagar com Cartão</a>
<a href="#" class="button small red btn_pag" value="boleto">Gerar Boleto</a>
```

Note que, assim como o `this`, `event.target` referir-se-á ao elemento que *ativou* o evento. Desse modo, `event.target` não será, necessariamente, o elemento que *registrou* o evento. Para saber mais, consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

## Passar o `this` pelo *handler* atributo no HTML

Quando você utiliza atributos como `onclick` diretamente no HTML, você pode passar valores como o `this` (ou o próprio `event`) como argumento para a função a ser executada:

```js
function handleClick(callerThis) {
  console.log(callerThis.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="handleClick(this)" value="card">Pagar com Cartão</a>
<a href="#" onclick="handleClick(this)" value="boleto">Gerar Boleto</a>
```

Saiba mais [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446548/69296).

Comment: como seria utilizando a função onclick="nomefunção()" ??

Comment: @MaykBr, editei a resposta. Mas nesse último caso você estaria fazendo bem mais diferente do que você fez no jQuery. :)

Comment: obrigado me ajudou muito, sim foi mais por questão de curiosidade mesmo